# Number of iterations to get desired accuracy in C (ln x, taylor polynomial)

Tags: c, iteration, floating-accuracy, polynomials

I am trying to write a c program to

1. get result of "n" iterations of taylor series for ln(x)
2. get number of iterations needed to get the result with desired accuracy compared to log(x) from

So far i have created two functions for taylor series, first one for 0 < x < 1 and second for x > 1. To make it simple, I will post just the second one because these functions work fine. The input is "x" as the parameter of ln() and "n" as the number of iterations. As I can't use math.h I had to create "xTOn" function which simply does the x^n. In this function I have implemented following formula:

[Taylor series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnpkJ.jpg)

```
double taylorTheSecond(double x, int n) // second formula for taylor x > 1
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum += xTOn((x-1)/x, i) / i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I have also the function to count number of needed iterations but it compares the result with the function log() from math.h, which is undiserable. It should be done by comparing two consecutive iterations but i have no idea how to do that because i don't understand what's the point when you compare two inaccurate numbers. Now, "x" is the parameter of ln function and "eps" is desired accuracy (e.g. 0.001 or 1e-3 ...).

```
#include <math.h>

int iterations(double x, double eps)
{
    int i = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        if (fabs(taylorTheSecond(x, i) - log(x)) <= eps)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }   

    return i;
}
```

This is really simple. But to count the iterations without using the math library, it just looks impossible to me. I will be grateful for any suggestions how to get this done :).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exit the loop when the fluctuation in the results of successive iterations falls below your desired resolution. i.e. `fabs(taylorTheSecond(x, i) - taylorTheSecond(x, i - 1)) < 1e-3` or whatever.

.. and obviously use a variable to store the previous value; also instead of re-calculating the Taylor series each time, just calculate the next term, and see if this falls below the desired resolution.

Comment: I see your point, at first this was my idea too, but then I don't get the exact number of iterations because the value of fluctutation can be much lower than the real value of accuracy compared to the exact result. Thanks for your reaction though.